# How do I create animations for a book and use them in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation

I want to create my first app as a child's book. I know that I need to create an animation and bring it into Xcode. I want to know what program I should use to create the animations and can you draw in that program or must I draw in 1 program and animate it in the next?

Thank You

Comment: You might want to sit back and rethink your app's idea.  Just sticking a video in your app isn't going to be very rewarding, is it?  You might want to try to make it be either interactive, or just have it be a video, not an app.

Comment: right, i want it interactive also! How would you suggest i go about this? As a first book!

Comment: Is this your first programming experience or just first iOS app?

Comment: Just my first app! i have about 2 years of experience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try looking at [this example](https://github.com/brow/leaves), which gives you a paper sliding effect.